# how initialize a kendo autocomplete widget at the document.ready() function

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui, datasource

My kendo autocomplete widget, gets data from a webservice c#, and it works fine.
But I see that the widget gets the data from the webservice when I type something in the keyboard.

I need to fire the bound event to data from its data, into the following function, not when typing something on keyboard:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//fire event here!!!
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say _I need to fire the bound event to data from its data_? That you want to bring "all" data from the server and let the client filter it then with the already received data?

Comment: Do you mean you want to bind data has soon has the autocomplete is created?

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, yes, i want bind data from the server as soon as the autocomplete is created, at the "$(document).ready(function(){});

at the moment, the bind data (the client side call to webservice) fires for the first time, when i type a key on keyboard.

i need it happens on the load of the document.

Comment: Can you show us your autocomplete initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have something like:

```
// DataSource definition
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
        read: {
            url : "service.json"
        }
    }
});
// Autocomplete definition
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: ds
});
```

So, just need to invoke `ds.read()` for loading it.

```
// Load DataSource using `transport.read`
ds.read();
```

Comment: Please, remove previous comment, I'm pretty sure that you are not :-)